# The 100 Coins Puzzle

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recreational-mathematics, puzzle

There are 10 sets of 10 coins. You know how much the coins should weigh. You know all the coins in one set of ten are exactly a hundredth of an ounce off, making the entire set of ten coins a tenth of an ounce off. You also know that all the other coins weight the correct amount. You are allowed to use an extremely accurate digital weighing machine only once.
How do you determine which set of 10 coins is faulty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all normal coins have a uniform weight:

I think you would want to number the sets $1,2,\ldots,10$. Then take $1$ coin from the first set, $2$ coins from the second set, $i$ coins from the $i$th set, and $10$ coins from the $10$th set. Then the weighing machine will display the correct weight minus $n$ hundredths of an ounce. Then the faulty set is the one from which you selected $n$ coins.

You could also do this by selecting $0,1,2,\ldots,9$ coins. I'm not sure if either strategy fails for any edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

IF we take one coin=10 gram,and we take one from the first stack,two from the second stack,three coins from the third and so on until we pick up ten coins from the tenth stack.we are assuming all the coins are genuine and add like 10+20+30+40+50+60+70+80+90+100=550 grams
now if we we get total weight 551,we will sure that the fake stack is the first since one coins weight in the first stack is 11
if 552 then the second and so on to 563

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. How is this answer different from the accepted answer ?.  Please refrain from answering old questions if you are not going to contribute anything new. It brings them un-necessarily to the top of some observable queue